# Decomposition of $GL_n$ representation

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory

Let $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ be a vector space of dimension $n$,
viewed as the standard representation of $GL_n$.
I know how to decompose
$S^2 V \otimes V=S^3 V\oplus S^{2,1}V$,
where $S^\mu$ is the Schur functor corresponding to a partition $\mu$.
I don't know how to deal with duals though,
for example what are decompositions (into irreps) of $S^2 V\otimes V^{\ast}$ and $S^{2}V\otimes S^{2}V^{\ast}$?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but maybe this is helpful. The wedge product $V \otimes \Lambda^{k-1}(V) \to \Lambda^k(V)$ is both $GL(V)$-equivariant and nondegenerate, so it produces an isomorphism

$$V^{\ast} \cong \Lambda^{k-1}(V) \otimes \Lambda^k(V)^{\ast}$$

where $\Lambda^k(V)^{\ast} \cong \Lambda^k(V)^{-1}$ (since this representation is $1$-dimensional). This is the functorial form of [Cramer's rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cramer%27s_rule). So in principle the problem reduces to understanding how $\Lambda^{k-1}(V)$ interacts with other Schur functors.